# Need Pentaho JSON without array

Tags: pentaho

I wanted to output json data not as array object and I did the changes mentioned in the pentaho document, but the output is always array even for the single set of values. I am using PDI 9.1 and I tested using the ktr from the below link

https://wiki.pentaho.com/download/attachments/25043814/json_output.ktr?version=1&modificationDate=1389259055000&api=v2

below statement is from https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/JSON+output

Another special case is when 'Nr. rows in a block' = 1.
If used with empty json block name output will looks like:

{
"name" : "item",
"value" : 25
}

My output comes like below

> { "": [ {"name":"item","value":25} ] }

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved myself. I have added another JSON input step and defined as below

$.wellDesign[0] to get the array as string object